# Pass post data jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I can' figure how to do that.

I have several hidden fields

```
<input type="hidden" id="order_1" name="order_1" value="1">
<input type="hidden" id="order_2" name="order_2" value="2">
<input type="hidden" id="order_3" name="order_3" value="3">

<input type="hidden" name="ids[]" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="ids[]" value="2">
<input type="hidden" name="ids[]" value="3">
```

etc..
The idea is to pass the data via ajax like this.

```
var id = $('input').attr('name')
$.post('http://foobar.com/ajax.php', {ids : ids, order: order}, function(data){

});
```

What I can't figure out is how to collect the data.

On the other side in ajax.php I wan't to get the values like this

```
echo $_POST['order_1'];
echo $_POST['order_2'];
......
etc
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your looking for `.serialize`. See the [api](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/).

Try something like this:

```
var postData = $('input:hidden').serialize();

$.post('http://foobar.com/ajax.php', postData, function(data){

});
```

Bear in mind the selector I used for the hidden inputs can be changed by you to be more specific, perhaps by using the form id.

Answer (score 0):

Mistake #1

```
<input type="hidden" id="order_1" name="order_1 value="1">
<input type="hidden" id="order_1" name="order_1 value="1">
<input type="hidden" id="order_1" name="order_1 value="1">
```

should be

```
<input type="hidden" id="order_1" name="order_1" value="1">
<input type="hidden" id="order_1" name="order_1" value="1">
<input type="hidden" id="order_1" name="order_1" value="1">
```

---

Mistake #2

**Never ever forever** use same id. Use different one ! Also for name attribute

---

Mistake #3

You pass

`$.post('http://foobar.com/ajax.php', {ids : ids`

instead of

`$.post('http://foobar.com/ajax.php', {ids : id`

---

**update**

Assuming

```
<input type="hidden" id="order_1" name="order_1" value="1">
<input type="hidden" id="order_2" name="order_2" value="2">
<input type="hidden" id="order_3" name="order_3" value="3">
```

and js:
    var yourArray = [];

```
$.each($("input[type='hidden']"), function(key, value){
  yourArray.push($(this).attr("name"));
});
```

pass it to ajax

`$.post('http://foobar.com/ajax.php', {ids : yourArray ...`

Comment: Actually the mistakes that you notice are fixed in my code. But I still can't get how to collect and pass the data to ajax

Answer (score 0):

This will post all your form data to ajax.php. You'll have to give your `<form>` tag an id (in this case its id='formId')

```
$.post('http://foobar.com/ajax.php', $('#formId').serializeArray());
```

You can request the ids with:

```
$ids = $_POST['ids'];
```

Answer (score 0):

To pass the values

```
<input type="hidden" id="order_1" name="order_1" value="1">
<input type="hidden" id="order_2" name="order_2" value="2">
<input type="hidden" id="order_3" name="order_3" value="3">

<input type="hidden" name="ids[]" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="ids[]" value="2">
<input type="hidden" name="ids[]" value="3">


var ids_arr = new Array();
 $("input[name='ids[]']").each(function() {
    ids_arr.push( $(this).val() );
 });
$.post('http://foobar.com/ajax.php', {"ids" :ids_arr , "order_1": $('#order_1').val(),"order_2":$('#order_2').val(),"order_3":$('#order_3').val()}, function(data){

});
```

For getting the values on php side

```
echo $_POST['order_1'];
echo $_POST['order_2'];
echo $_POST['order_3'];
var_dump($_POST['ids']);
```